# Permissions to edit only the Status of an order

Tags: 7, commerce

I have created a role called "Order Manager", he should be able to

1. View all the orders.
2. Update the status of any order.
3. Not be able to edit(can edit only the status field, nothing else)/or delete any order.

How do I achieve this in Drupal Commerce?

Comment: I don't think there's a specific permission for that.  One basic approach you could take would be to revoke edit permissions and then use a combination of the Flag and Rules modules to allow the Order Manager role to change the status (i.e., not directly but instead through flagging which triggers a rules component which changes the status).

Comment: Makes sense. But how come Drupal commerce doesn't have that permission set? I thought it was a basic usecase in a store managemen. Nevertheless, commerce kickstart is an awesome product.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Views Bulk Operations
2. Clone the default user/orders/% view of all the orders, and restrict it to your new role.
3. Add a Bulk Operations field to the view in step 2.
4. Follow the steps outlined as you add the new field from step 3. You can limit which status states the user can select while modifying.